# Create a new public team within Microsoft Teams from a website

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We know that it's possible to start a Microsoft Teams conversation via a link on a website like the following:

`<a href="MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=john.doe@my-organisation.com>Start direct MS Teams Chat</a>`

Now we're searching for a way to create a new public team for all members of our organization within MS-Teams from the outside. With a simple link that won't be possible as we need to know the Teams link to this public team.

So from UX side we want to have first a button

`<button>Start new discussion in MS Teams for this issue</button>`

And once a user has klicked this button we replace it by this button:

`<a href="MSTeams:/link-to-the-new-public-team>Join the discussion for this issue in MS Teams</a>`

Is it understandable what we are trying to achieve?

Are there any MS Teams-API methods to achieve this behavior?

Create a new public team within Microsoft Teams from the outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with a link, like you can create a new chat.

But you can create a team using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

```js
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
  "displayName": "My Sample Team",
  "description": "My Sample Team’s Description"
}
```